# How to view apple watch screen on mac

Tags: ios, device, apple-watch, wwdc

(As the title says), I would like to know if it is possible to see the screen of the apple watch on the mac (much like they do in the WWDC videos). I need to make a demonstration (to a remote client), so it would be nice if I could do such. I’ve been searching for a solution, but no luck so far.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this? I am also interested in a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xcode 7, you can set Watch as the target for the simulator.

Comment: I have already used the simulator on previous demonstrations. However, this time I need to show features as push notifications and voice recognition, and they are not available on the simulator. I need to show the real device. Any suggestion?

Comment: @user3071284, there is an icon on the iOS simulator for apple watch, what does that do?

Comment: Hello Caleb, if you are asking for the app "apple watch" in the ios simulator, this app open the settings of the app running on the apple watch